# QuotaService.RecordEvent low performance 60 ms

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

We have a page that has a load time of 5.8 seconds. The long load time seems to be related to Google's QuotaService.RecordEvent which has a latency of 60 ms. Any thoughts on what might be causing this latency? And what could be done speed it up?

In Chrome (v31) when the search page is loading the maps, the entire page is not scrollable. This is not the case in Safari (v7) or Firefox (v26).

Issue can be replicated using this link. 
http://voradius.nl/search?product=de+g+van+geluk&location=1083xh&submit=Zoeken

Comment: It would help to see your slow loading code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

The QuotaService will count things that are affected by usage-limits(e.g. Map-loads).

This will not be done when you load the API, e.g. a Map-Load happens(and will be counted) when you have successfully created a `google.maps.Map`-instance(let's assume when the tilesloaded-event fires the first time). Of course there will be a latency, because it takes some time to initialize a map.

But this will not slow down the loading of the page, because usually you initialize the map when the document/window has finished loading.

The reason must be something else.